# Why can't I use my microphone in Amazon WorkSpaces?

Tags: microphone, aws

I'm connecting to Amazon WorkSpaces using version 4.0.2.2087. I have tried using my internal mic, a USB headset, Bluetooth headset, and 3.5mm audio jack headset. I can hear audio just fine with all methods but the microphone does not work once I connect to Amazon WorkSpaces. The mic does function outside of Amazon WorkSpaces.

I have tried to disconnect the WorkSpaces client, change the system Sound settings to use my headset, then reconnect to WorkSpaces.

I have tried to disable and enable.

I have tried to update the driver.

I have checked my browser (Chrome, Edge, and Firefox) permissions to ensure access to my mic is granted.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled WorkSpaces

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Which version of macOS are you using?

Comment: Perhaps it is not a Mqc issue but an Amazon Spaces issue - have you asked them?